# How loop per unique variable in jinja?

Tags: python, group-by, jinja2

**Issue**

How do you loop per unique variable/row in jinja rather than looping through all rows? For example I have

```
GroupA
GroupA  
GroupB  
GroupB
```

I would like to output per unique row/variable:

```
GroupA  
GroupB
```

rather than 4 rows

**Updated**

**My data**

Group A Brazil  1 3 1 3
Group A Croatia  1 3 1 3
Group B Italy  1 3 1 3
Group B England  1 3 1 3

So I would like it to look like this after:

**Group A**

Brazil  1 3 1 3
Croatia  1 3 1 3

**Group B**
Italy  1 3 1 3
England  1 3 1 3

Comment: How was the data sourced? You usually do this kind of filtering outside of the template.

Comment: Made some changes above. Using sqlite

Comment: Why not use a `DISTINCT` query then to get distinct results from the query?

Comment: Or have your Python code that queries, build a nested structure from that data (grouping with nested lists).

Comment: Thanks, how do you do a distinct query in jinja. Yeah I thought about grouping with nested lists. Maybe a little complicated?

Answer (score 2):

Found it, used default(dict)

results represents my named tuple

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k in results:
  d[k[0]].append(k[1:4])

e= collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
print e.keys()
```

e.keys = represent each group

Comment: Is this Jinja ?